# How to substitute multiple characters including beginning of line and end of line in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to add '|' at the beginning of line, end of line, and replace whitespace with '|'. For example,

```
123 456 789
abc def hij
```

should become

```
|123|456|789|
|abc|def|hij|
```

The command `1,$s/[ $^]/|/g` only replaces the whitespace but not the ^ (beginning of line) and $ (end of line).

What is the right regex to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can use this https://regex101.com/r/z9LGaU/2/

Answer (score 2):

The regex to be used will be,

```
"^|$| "
```

Which when have to be written for VIM editor becomes this as you need to escape `|` with `\`,

```
:%s/^\|$\| /\|/g
```

Open your file, then just copy paste above string and hit enter, which will give you desired results.